# How do I size an image to fit inside another image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So as many of you can tell, I'm pretty new to CSS and how all of it works, and in my attempts to build a website, I want to use this image http://cdn-production.codecademy.com/assets/imac-1de402798fb7b26c5952ffb70fc9ee89.svg and fit a picture inside of it

The end product would look something like this http://gyazo.com/1e8ea4b5a65241fb5c789ad177cef20c

How do I get an image to fit inside of another image?

Comment: Simply place an image positioned relatively inside a div with a fixed size that has the background image of the monitor.  You could also get creative with padding and margins to position if you wanted.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, would you be able to tell me how I would go about doing that?

Comment: What is your specific question?  `<div><img /></div>`, and then your CSS, `background-image` for the div.  Set `height` and `width` as needed, `position: relative; top: 10px; left: 10px;` or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code..

### HTML

```
<span class="mac">
    <span class="screen">
        <img src="http://th06.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/i/2011/133/a/0/mac_desktop_xd_screenshot___by_ferxho0-d3g8qer.png"/>
    </span>
</span>
```

### CSS

```
span.mac{
width:450px;
height:371px;
display:inline-block;
background-image:url(http://cdn-production.codecademy.com/assets/imac-1de402798fb7b26c5952ffb70fc9ee89.svg);
background-size: 450px 371px;
}
span.mac span.screen{
width:412px;
height:235px;
display:inline-block;
margin:19px;
overflow:hidden;
}
span.mac span.screen img{
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
span.mac span.screen img.fit{
height:100%;
}
```

And Remember , The image width will fit with screen,,
and if image height is smaller than screen height it, the image height will fit the screen.
else balance part of the image will go inside of the screen..

Like this : 
http://jsfiddle.net/kKaw4/

if you want to fit the image height also ..
please add a class 'fit' for the img
Like this `<img src="http://www.example.com/image.png" class="fit" />`
Link http://jsfiddle.net/kKaw4/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use one image as `background:` through css and other image as `<img />` tag.

[Here is demo for it.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJGxn)

Make sure you have the image tag in proportion, so it does not stretch.
HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <img src="http://www.designsnext.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/nature-wallpapers-17.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
  background: url(http://cdn-production.codecademy.com/assets/imac-1de402798fb7b26c5952ffb70fc9ee89.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: 740px;
  width: 910px;
  padding: 38px 0 0 39px;
}

.outer img {
  width: 823px;
  height: 469px
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in the answer and rely less on CodePen.

Comment: Thanks @JonP for suggestion, I'll do the same henceforth.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

http://jsfiddle.net/mukilr/MDC2s/2/

You can use CSS positioning property called absolute to do so.

The code Im using is like so:

```
<div id='A'>
       <img style='position:absolute'src='http://cdn-production.codecademy.com/assets/imac-1de402798fb7b26c5952ffb70fc9ee89.svg'></img>
       <img style='position:absolute;height:450px;width:800px;top:50px;left:50px;z-index:999' src='http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Windows-Broken-1440x900.jpg'></img>
</div>
```

When the absolute positioning property is used, an element is positioned relative to its parent html node. Here we are positioning both images relative to its parent `<div>`. This is important as this allows both images to be aligned in the same area.

To ensure that the second image appears above the first, you can give a higher z-index property for the image which is meant to be above the other.